# Steam Inventory not showing up?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

Just did a few trades for CS:GO and after a while steam shows that i have 0 items in my entire inventory on steam (Steam items, CS:GO items, TF2 items, etc.). However my items do show up in-game. Is this a problem with the Steam API by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Steam Community services are experiencing some issues at the moment. You can check the status over here: [steamstat.us](http://steamstat.us/).